# Conditional linking to other html pages

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am new to `HTML/CSS` and in this project intend to create a simple web page in such a way that each page links to three other `HTML` pages.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="homePage.html" id="homePage">Home Page</a>
    <a href="about.html" id="about">about</a>
    <a href="projects.html" id="projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="contact.html" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

My **questions**:

1. Is it possible to link to other pages other than the page itself via
   programming (to write if `page_name == link.html` then exclude it from
   the links)? e.g., I want to tell my `HTML` that if I am in the "about"
   page, don't add the link to this page.
2. If that is possible, how I can fill the self-link button without using `JS`.

Comment: You can use separate navigation code for individual pages and organize <a> tags based on the page.

Comment: I see that you have multiple html pages, and you could simply remove or replace the href=" --.html " of the same page and add " # " in its place, its without JS.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. HTML isn't a programming language and has no flow control or logic capabilities. You could achieve this via server-side rendering ([express](https://expressjs.com/) or [php](https://www.php.net/) or whatever) or via static site generation ([gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/), etc.).

Otherwise you could (of course) modify the nav on each page accordingly, but I understand and agree that that's less than ideal.

This is a bit of a stretch, but you could link to `homePage.html#homePage` and use the [`CSS :target pseudo-selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) to hide the current item or give it special css treatment, but this is sort of a brittle hack and it will break down if the fragment (`#homePage, #projects`, etc.) isn't present in the browser's url.